# Bubble sort in Javascript : Alert Missing problem

Tags: javascript

**This is the assignment I am trying to complete:**

> This file should contain a text box named mydata that collects the numbers separated by commas.
> A button named "databtn" is used to invoke a javascript function named `bubble_sort()`. This function does not accept any arguments.
> The data must be sorted and displayed as an alert as indicated in the snapshot.
>
> **Required Output:**
> [image]

**This is what I tried:**

```js
function swap(arr,first,second){
    var temp=arr[first];
    arr[first]=arr[second];
    arr[second]=temp;
}
 
function bubble_sort() {
    var str=document.getElementById("input").value;
    var arr;
    if(str.length===0){
        arr=new Array;
    }
    else{
        arr=str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    }
    var len=arr.length,
    i,j,stop;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        for(j=0,stop=len-i;j<stop;j++){
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
               swap(arr,j,j+1);
            }
        }
    }
    alert(arr)
}
```

```html
<form>
    Enter data to sort : <input type="text" name="mydata" id="input" ><br>
    <input type="button" id="data" onclick="bubble_sort()" 
           name="databtn" value="Sort Data" />
</form>
```

I get the correct output (except in the case of negative numbers), however, it shows ***"Fail-Alert missing"*** and Test case failed.
I cannot figure out why, I would appreciate any advice, Thanks!

Comment: Please provide with us with code instead of image of code,thanks.

Comment: What should happen when your input does not have digits, like "this_is_a_test". Currently your code produces an exception. Possibly the tester expects you to alert something?

Comment: @trincot I tried handling the exception. Thanks, it worked with the alert missing problem.

Comment: OK, I have posted an answer that deals with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your code does not deal well with invalid input, i.e. when there are no digits at all in your input ("this_is_a_test").

So change:

```
if(str.length===0){
    arr=new Array;
}
else{
    arr=str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
}
```

to:

```
arr=(str.match(/-?\d+/g) || []).map(Number);
```

The `|| []` deals with the case when there is no digit at all. In that case the `null` return from `match` will be replaced with an empty array (`[]`).

The `-?` addition to the regular expression will allow to also match negative integers correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in this line:

`arr=str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);`

you match only numbers without `-` symbol.
If your input is a guaranteed list of numbers then you can simply split by comma:

`arr=str.split(',').map(Number);`

Comment: @ijustdontgetit if this solved your problem please mark this answer as solution :)